# Modifying format of Date request header in HttpClient on post

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

I'm trying to post to a url, and I'm using the HttpClient class to do it. I'm having an issue setting the Date header.

At first I was just letting .NET handle the date. But apparently for this url that I'm posting to, the date header needs to be in a specific format, so I tried changing it.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = currentDate;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Date", currentDate.ToString("MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"));
```

But I get this error:

> System.FormatException: The format of value 'Dec 30 15:00:00 2015' is invalid.

I tried changing it to a simpler format of "dd/MM/yyyy", but I still get the same error.

Is there any way for me to modify that Date header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See a similar problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/14187cc8-cba0-4995-aadd-0db8613cb43a/custom-date-header-format-for-httpclient?forum=winappswithcsharp

Please try this: DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzzz");